# Reducing the number of anonymous functions needed in calls to D3's `attr` and the like

Tags: d3.js

So I've got some rudimentary code that works just fine [BTW I'm not using any scales yet]:

```
        svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length);
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - (d.close * 4);
           })
           .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
           .attr("height", function(d) {
                return d.close * 4;
           })
           .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.close * 10) + ")";
           })
           .append("title").text(function(d) {
                if (d.date == null) {
                    return "Close: " + d.close;
                } else {
                    return "Date: " + dateFmt(d.date)
                         + "\nClose: " + d.close;
                }
           });
```

Now I'm told I can reduce the calls to `attr` by having the first argument be an object of name to value pairs like:

```
        svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr({
           "x": function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length);
           },
           "y": function(d) {
                return h - (d.close * 4);
           },
           "width": w / dataset.length - barPadding,
           "height": function(d) {
                return d.close * 4;
           },
           "fill": function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.close * 10) + ")";
           }})
           .append("title").text(function(d) {
                if (d.date == null) {
                    return "Close: " + d.close;
                } else {
                    return "Date: " + dateFmt(d.date)
                         + "\nClose: " + d.close;
                }
           });
```

It seems to me, however, that it'd be even more terse if the first argument could be a function (as the second can be) which returns such a specific object of name value pairs. Like this:

```
        svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr(function(d,i) {
             return {
                "x": i * (w / dataset.length),
                "y": h - (d.close * 4),
                "width": w / dataset.length - barPadding,
                "height": d.close * 4,
                "fill": "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.close * 10) + ")"
           })
           .append("title").text(function(d) {
                return ((d.date != null)
                        ? "Date: " + dateFmt(d.date) + "\n"
                        : "")
                    + "Close: " + d.close;
           });
```

The latter doesn't work, but maybe I'm missing the better way to form this so that fewer anonymous function definitions need be specified. If so I could be a little more descriptive with the repeated `d` and `i` if I wanted to. Is there some such alternative mode available which I've missed?

Comment: titles are elements in SVG, not attributes as they are in html.

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh, thanks, I'll try that and maybe update the question if it works. It was an aside from what I was hoping to do with terser syntax.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, It works and I've updated the question.

Comment: This feature is definitely high up on my wish list. I have myself looked into this, but found no solution either. Personally, I  am not very keen on @Gilsha's way, because it involve another method, i.e. `.each()`, instead of providing this functionality directly for `.attr()` and `.style()`. But, by now, it seems to be the only possible hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .each(function (d,i) {
       d3.select(this)
         .attr({
             "x": i * (w / dataset.length),
             "y": h - (d.close * 4),
             "width": w / dataset.length - barPadding,
             "height": d.close * 4,
             "fill": "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.close * 10) + ")"
         });
   });
```

Comment: This is definitely closer to what I hoped for; the d3.select(this) is a bit unexpected though. If after the `.each(…)` I wanted to `.append(…)` something else, would I still be in the context of the rect?

Comment: You would (which is good as you'll need to add a title). You could create a separate variable though to append other elements.

Comment: Inside each function, `this` is an html element. I used `d3.select(this)` to convert it into a d3 selection, so that attributes can be applied in the d3 way.  And you are in the same context of rect after the `.each(..)` function. You can append the title like this. `.each(...).append("title").text("TooltipText")`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the features I have definitely been missing every now and then.

There have been some discussions about pros & cons on [issue #277](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/277) and similarly for `.classed()` on [issue #2254](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2254) with both sides having good arguments. The best one *against* including it into `.attr()` was brought up by Mike Bostock in one of his [comments](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/277#issuecomment-7513815):

> This preserves D3’s philosophy of encouraging only values (and not names) to be specified as functions.

Notwithstanding, the wait may soon be over! As I just noticed, we may see this feature in the near future with the upcoming [D3 v4](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2109#issuecomment-119761206). The consensus now seems to be to not further overload the methods `.attr()`, `.property()` and `.style()` to avoid cluttering those methods' signatures. The change as it is currently in the [repo](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) is implemented in the new methods `.attrs()`, `.properties()` and `.styles()`. Note the plural names of these methods.

---

For the time being, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35263948/4235784) posted by Gilsha is obviously correct and as close, as one can get to this with D3 v3. It has also been proposed by Mike Bostock in his [comment](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/277#issuecomment-7513815) to the above mentioned issue, but to some [others](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/277#issuecomment-14163271), including myself, it feels somewhat hacky.